# PDO UPDATE not updating the database

Tags: php, pdo

My update statement dosn't seem to be updating my database but I'm unsure why, I've used the same code elsewhere in my script and it works fine.

```
try
{
    // update the live documents details
    $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE docs SET ref = :ref, rev = :rev, updated = :updated WHERE id = :id");
    $sth->bindParam(':ref', $ref);
    $sth->bindParam(':rev', $rev);
    $sth->bindParam(':updated', $date);
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $currentid);
    $sth->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    throw new Your_Exception($e->getMessage());
    // or
    throw $e;
}
```

I've tried manually inputting a query into the database using PHPMyAdmin just to test I have my table names correct and the query does work as expected.

```
UPDATE docs SET ref =  'FMS',
rev =  'D',
updated = NOW( ) WHERE id =73
```

So this leaves me thinking I have an error in my PDO statement. Although the try catch block isn't giving any errors.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the query in your PHP code?

Comment: If you are binding the string "NOW()" for `updated` you might have problems with that, instead of it, put a PHP datetime format

Comment: @RoyalBg I'm passing the date like so date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date("Y-m-d");

Then using the $date variable to pass into the PDO statement

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for your help very constructive

Comment: I just found this funny. Don't take it personal. Imagine you have the namespace `Your` and `My` and `Hello`.. Hihi. That's funny! :) Check the answer of @YourCommonSense. This should help you.

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Comment: @hek2mgl Agreed, I'd prefer `throw new My_Exception()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all possible reasons

- there is an error in the query (which have to be thrown)
- there is no data to match the criteria.
- the data is already updated - nothing to change.
- you are checking not the table/database which you were updating.

Please verify all the issues listed.

By the way, to be able to see thrown errors you have to [configure PHP properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help I will look into this now, im connecting to my database like so:

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {

  echo $e->getMessage();

}

would this be enough to throw errors correctly in my above code?